# Pixel-Perfect Collision With Rotation

Tags: xna, c#

I know how to implement pixel perfect collision, but how would I do this with rotations applied to my sprite?

Comment: I could answer this question if I knew exactly what you meant by "pixel perfect collision". I can only assume you're talking about some common array method for XNA/Flash. Maybe you can link to a resource that talks about what you already know? It's just not clear what you're talking about.

Comment: Official tutorial: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel_transformed